# Is it bad for one to let bits of one's personal life become known online?

Tags: technology, internet, tznius-modesty, writing-printing

Isaac Moses [wrote](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4266/meya-alafim-mi-yodeya-gershon-gold-yodeya):

> Over the years, Gershon Gold has demonstrated great research skills, often coming up with on-point sources for interesting Halachic questions very quickly. He has also been an exemplar of [tzeniut](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary/592#592), concentrating on writing great questions and answers and keeping his personal life to himself.

I'm unsure why keeping one's personal life to oneself might be important.

Is it bad for one to let bits of one's personal life become known online?

For example, in [this Mi Yodeya post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47556/polite-way-to-break-up-with-a-chavrusa/81780#81780), I disclose that I have ADHD; this makes my answer more believable. In other online posts, I might share a personal anecdote or two; this can add flavor and interest to a post which might otherwise be academic and boring.

Comment: I think that the better answer will come from the author of this statement @Isaac Moses right?

Comment: @kouty: He can answer; but so can anyone else. I'd be curious to hear multiple opinions. You can't ping Isaac here, since he's never commented here. If you want to ping him, you can probably do so in [chat], as long as he's been present in the chat room within the past seven days.